# Help with $(P\wedge Q) \vee\neg P \vdash \neg Q \rightarrow \neg P$

Tags: proof-writing, computational-mathematics, natural-deduction

$$(P ∧ Q) ∨ ¬P ⊢ ¬Q → ¬P,\qquad P, ¬(¬Q → R) ⊢ ¬(P↔ Q)$$
I am stuck in this, can't wrap my head around it. Need to prove fitch style

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: to be honest, for first one, I tried to sub proof the disjunction and got P using disjunction elimination, worked out well in my head but the proof checker keeps giving error for " Is not a proper application of the rule ¬I " and I am still banging my head. Can't really understand

Comment: The first one isn't valid, so it's no wonder that you're not getting anywhere with it.

Comment: oh yea my bad, I made a mistake. It's correct now. Thx tho. More thanks if you can help.

Comment: In the second equation, I think you mean $P$ instead of $R$

Comment: um no, I checked everything is correct. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is one of the Fitch-style proofs that I can think of.

$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{(P\land Q)\lor\lnot P}{\fitch{P\land Q}{Q\\\fitch{\lnot Q}{\bot\\\lnot P}\\\lnot Q\to\lnot P}\\\fitch{\lnot P}{\fitch{\lnot Q}{\lnot P}\\\lnot Q\to\lnot P}\\\lnot Q\to\lnot P}\qquad\raise{4ex}{\fitch{P\\\lnot(\lnot Q\to R)}{\fitch{P\leftrightarrow Q}{Q\\\fitch{\lnot Q}{\bot\\ R}\\\lnot Q\to R\\\bot}\\\lnot(P\leftrightarrow Q)}}$$

I will leave you to derive the reasoning of each line.

Comment: thank you, really appreciate it.

Comment: @itsmeass Good to hear! You can accept this answer if this solved your problem.